# Making html css website function properly on ios devices

Tags: android, html, ios, css, mobile

Have the following website. Seems to work great on Linux and Windows using a multitude of browsers. Also works fine on my droid phone and tablet. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out why it will not work on IOS devices properly. Can someone give me some pointers as to how one can make a site like this more ios friendly. Most of my friends and family use ios ofcourse. LOL...

http://www.GinaAndTamer.com

Please check out the site on your PC and then on iOS products. Not matter what I try to change it doesn't seem to help with making it more compatabile with iOS products. I really would rather not create a whole new site, however, can someone point me to how to automatically redirect to the mobile site depending on device?

Some additional info that I have found and will use barring another solution.

Some additional information, I have found that I can make device specific css files using something similar to:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {    
    /* Put your iPhone 3g styles in here */ 
}
```

Also, if I will use redirection to a completely new site, I can use the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "YOUR-MOBILE-SITE.com";
}
//-->
</script>
The approach using user agent looks like this:
`code`
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   location.replace("http://YOUR-MOBILE-SITE.com");
}
-->
</script>
```

Thanks,
Tamer

Comment: Some additional information, I have found that I can make device specific css files using something similar to:

Also, if I will use redirection to a completely new site, I can use the following javascript code:

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "YOUR-MOBILE-SITE.com";
}
//-->
</script>
The approach using user agent looks like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   location.replace("http://YOUR-MOBILE-SITE.com");
}
-->
</script>

Answer (score 0):

It unfortunate i cannot comment, so this might not act as an answer but the issue is not the phone, it has to do with your css. you have fixed sizes so it will affact the way the device render it.
Try to use percentage (%) as values for your divs width and height, and secondly add this to your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I will give that a try. I already have the viewport statement in there because I knew I would need it for multiple devices. Thanks for the suggestion. However, besides things possibly looking funky; which is not my issue; the actual button and links on the first page do not even work. I am assuming this has very little to do with the sizing issue; although, I could be wrong and will try to alter everything to percentages; although not sure that will help very much in this situation. Thanks for the suggestion though.